# implementing Fast Fourier Transform in MSP430 microcontroller

Tags: signal-processing, microprocessors

I am trying to perform image processing operations in msp430 microcontrollers.
Is it possible to implement 2d fast fourier transform in MSP430 microcontrollers?
And im looking for an fft library for msp430. Where can i find it?

Comment: What you've asked is a yes/no question, so you might want to reword your question a bit (note however, that asking for library recommendations is off-topic on StackOverflow).

Comment: That's easy; just replace the MSP430 with a DSP.

Comment: I'm a very satisfied user of Mark Borgerding's KISS FFT library (https://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/). It has a fast integer implementation, including a version optimized for real-valued input signals, and is written in C. There is also a C++ version for floating-point if that's of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it using 2 pass 1D FFT algorithm:
Code:
https://github.com/dhyandeep/skynet